# Click 2 elements at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick, element

I have a scenario where a user can choose **1 element** or **2 elements** to click 
If the user choosed **2 elements** he can choose 2 elements in a single click but only to its neighbour element 
Ex: 
If user click on Elem 1 container, container below will be active or clicked 
**Elem 1** and **Elem 2**
 
If user click on Elem 3 container, container below will be active or clicked 
**Elem 2** and **Elem 3**
 
Moreover if **user clicked on Elem 2** it will depend on the nearest area where the user clicked(the **Y axis**) if it will be partnered with Elem 1 or Elem 3 
But **NOT** Elem 1 to 3 because there is a gap between them(the Elem 2) and as I've mention only the neighbour container.

I am using ReactJS

[image]

```
<div class="myClass">
  Elem 1
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  Elem 2
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  Elem 3
</div>
```

Comment: are you using jquery also in your project?

Comment: using react, so jquery is fine, have any idea?

Comment: @Drew, do you mean selecting two elements that are directly next to each other, or Clicking one element to select it and automatically its neighbor is also selected in that single click?

Comment: @iamcastelli your first statement will do

Comment: If i click elem 1 then automatically its next neighbour elem2 would get selected right?

Comment: Yes, I have cols and rows in my project, just going to figure out the x and y later after I get an idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: @bhavik edited my question

Comment: Please checkout my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Edit 1
>
> Based on the OP's subsequent comments, I realized they also wanted the second selected item to depend on how close the item is to the **click position**. I made some updates.

See updated React [Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-items-select-5r4pi)

---

#### App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ElementsList = () => {
  // 1. List of Items, they could be anything
  const items = ["Elem 1", "Elem 2", "Elem 3", "Element 4", "Element 5"];

  // 2. Track the selected items in state
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (e, index) => {
    // 7. Extract the click position and element height from the event target.
    const nextItems = getNextSelections({
      currentIndex: index,
      totalItems: items.length,
      elementHeight: e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      distanceFromTop: e.clientY - e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top
    });

    // 4. Do whatever you want with the selected items :), then update state
    setSelectedItems(nextItems);
  };

  return (
    <div className="List">
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <div
          key={value}
          className={`myClass ${
            // 5. Conditionally set selected class if index is present in selected Items array
            selectedItems.includes(index) ? "selected" : ""
          }`}
          // 6. Capture the click event and the index of the selected item
          onClick={e => handleClick(e, index)}
        >
          {value}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>2 Items Selector</h1>
      <ElementsList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

#### getNextSelections helper

```js
// Helper to get Select items based on mouse position
const getNextSelections = ({
  currentIndex, // Index of the clicked Item
  totalItems, // Total number of items in the list
  elementHeight, // Height of the bounding rectangle of the element
  distanceFromTop // Distance of Mouse click postion from top of boudning rectangle of the element
}) => {
  // A. Return first and second item if first item is clicked, exit early
  if (currentIndex <= 0) return [0, 1];

  // B. Return last and second last if last item is clicked and exit early
  if (currentIndex === totalItems - 1) return [currentIndex - 1, currentIndex];

  // C. If clicked in top half of the element, return previous and current item
  if (distanceFromTop < elementHeight / 2) {
    console.log("Cicked Next to the Top of Element");
    return [currentIndex - 1, currentIndex];
  }

  // D. Otherwise return current and next item indicies
  return [currentIndex, currentIndex + 1];
};
```

---

#### styles.css

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.List {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.myClass {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: solid 4px black;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.myClass.selected {
  background: rgb(236, 174, 174);
  transition: background 1s;
}
.myClass:last-child {
  border: solid 4px black;
}
```

---

I have added a helper to conditionally check the click position from the top of the selected element's bounding rectangle. Followed these assumptions.

1. If the first item is clicked, just choose the first and second items.`[A]`
2. Choose the last and second last item if the last one is clicked. `[B]`
3. For elements in the middle of the list, choose the previous item as the second selection if the click happens in the top half of the clicked item's bounding rectangle `[C]`, otherwise choose the previous item. `[D]`

[Code Sandbox: Multiple Items Select with Mouse Proximity](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-items-select-5r4pi)

> #### Edit 2
>
> In your comments you say the list has rows and columns :( You can extend the helper to account for the horizontal proximity using `getBoundingClientRect().left and width`, and use the same approach to select the index of items to the side closest to the click.
>
> #### Edit 3
>
> Had removed the approach where the next selected item doesn't depend on the position of the mouse click, but the code can be found in this [Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60485017/1) of this post here and the [Codesandbox "Multiple Items Select without Mouse Proximity"](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-items-select-without-mouse-proximity-5r4pi)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll just figure out the X-Y depending on the clicked area if it should clicked above or below container because when I clicked elem 2 it always goes partner with elem 3, it should depends on the nearest coordinates  so Elem 1 has a chance

Comment: @DrewCordano, I see you have accepted this answer. Glad it was helpful. However based on your comments I was working on the case where the second  item to be selected depends on how close you are to the edge, if the bottom edge, the next one is selected, and the previous one is elected if clicked close to the top. Would you be interested for me to update the answer with those cases?

Comment: I think you comment on the wrong section, I'm actually using a fullcalendar with events on it and user has an option to choose between 1 hour and 2 hours for UI and UX purposes.

Comment: I can't find any answer related to this interesting question and I'm sure people can benefit from your answer, thanks mate cheers!

Comment: Id like to ask where was the previous code sandbox link?

Comment: I updated the sandbox inplace when I updated the answer, but you can find the code to that sandbox in the [first revision of this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60485017/1) before the edits

Comment: Just got an extra time today, gonna study your previous code before moving. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are most welcome. Recreated the previous approach in this [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-items-select-with-no-proximity-5r4pi), for items selection without considering mouse position at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a solution for this using **javascript only**

In this approach i have used **Event Bubbling Concept** too.
You can check it out at https://jsfiddle.net/harshapache/dhqnrvwx/

---

**Important methods of DOM (javascript):**

- **check your div has class(Eg: active)**
  *event.target.classList.contains("active");*
- **Next Sibling Element** *event.target.nextElementSibling*
- **Previous Sibling Element** event.target.previousElementSibling
- **Add Class**  *event.target.classList.add("active");*
- **Remove Class**  *event.target.classList.remove("active");*

---

**HTML**

```
  <div id="myClassWrapper">
     <div class="myClass">Elem 1</div>
     <div class="myClass">Elem 2</div>
     <div class="myClass">Elem 3</div>
  </div>
```

---

**JS**

```
    var selectedElements = 0;
    var myClassWrapper = document.getElementById('myClassWrapper');
        myClassWrapper.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var isMyClassClicked = event.target.classList.contains("myClass");


    if(isMyClassClicked){
      var isActive = event.target.classList.contains("active");
      if(isActive){
       //Do Unselect
       event.target.classList.remove("active");
       selectedElements--;
      }
      else{
        //Do Select
        //1.Check selectedElemnts not equal to 2
        if(selectedElements == 2) alert('You already selected two elements');
         if(selectedElements == 1){
         //check neighbour has active or not
         var isNextElemActive = event.target.nextElementSibling ? event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("active") : false;
         var isPrevElemActive = event.target.previousElementSibling ? event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("active") : false;
         if(isNextElemActive || isPrevElemActive){
           event.target.classList.add("active");
           selectedElements++;
         }else{
           alert("you can't select it");
         }
        }
        if(selectedElements == 0){
          event.target.classList.add("active");
          selectedElements++;
        }
       }
     }
   });
```

Comment: you did not understand my question, i qoute
"If the user choosed 2 elements he can choose 2 elements in a single click"

Comment: Sorry, I will Update

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery's .next()` method to find next div.

```js
$(".myClass").on("click", function() {
    $('.myClass').css("background","none");
    $(this).css("background", "red");
    $(this).next(".myClass").css("background", "red");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
  Elem 1
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  Elem 2
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  Elem 3
</div>
```

Comment: Just an issue with jquery's next, Coz if user clicked on Elem 2 it should depends on the nearest div Elem 1 or Elem 2 using getBoundingClientRect and I'm going to put a height to solve this matter. So at the moment it should be clicked on Elem 3 to highlight Elem 2, not the other way around.

Comment: Like if i click on elem 3 then it should highligh elem 2, if i click on elem 2 it should highlight elem 1. Right?

Comment: yes but on elem 2 i will base it on its nearest elements where i click
imagine they all have a height of 50px if i cick on the top of the text of <p> Elem 2 <p>  Elem 1 will be highlighted, if below the text of <p> Elem 2 </p>  Elem 3 will be highlighted using the getBoundClientRect

Comment: @DrewCordano, updated answer to support proximity selection using `getBoundClientRect` :)

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question, so you have 3 elements and all you want is if you click on the above part of the element both above and below one will be highlighted, Same goes for the bottom part if you bottom part of the element   both above and below one will be highlighted 
for this functionality, I have tested a jQuery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".oneEbottom").on("click", function(event){
    $(event.delegateTarget).css("background-color", "red");
    $(".twoE").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".oneE").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".threeE").css("background-color", "white");
  });

  $(".twoEabove").on("click", function(event){
    $(event.delegateTarget).css("background-color", "red");
    $(".oneE").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".twoE").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".threeE").css("background-color", "white");
  });

  $(".twoEbottom").on("click", function(event){
    $(event.delegateTarget).css("background-color", "red");
    $(".threeE").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".twoE").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".oneE").css("background-color", "white");
  });

  $(".threeEabove").on("click", function(event){
    $(event.delegateTarget).css("background-color", "red");
    $(".threeE").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".twoE").css("background-color", "red");
     (".oneE").css("background-color", "white");
  });
});
</script>
```

you can use this simple script  for this funtionality but you have to link the jQuery file in you  tag

```
<head>

<style>
.a {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>






<div class="oneE a" >
<div class="oneEinner">Element 1</div>
<div class="oneEbottom s"><small>to highlight Element 1 & 2</small></div>
</div>

<div class="twoE a">
    <div class="twoEabove s"><small>to highlight Element 1 & 2</small></div>
    <div class="twoEinner">Element 2</div>
    <div class="twoEbottom s"><small>to highlight Element 2 & 3</small></div>
</div>

<div class="threeE a">
<div class="threeEabove s"><small>to highlight Element 2 & 3</small></div>
<div class="threeEinner">Element 3</div>
</div>
```

As you see for more clarification I put a small text in each section to check the above and bottom when you are going to click on it, you can remove it this is only for testing purpose

Comment: This is the example you can go through this link: https://jsfiddle.net/saad_jafri/o5w6uLpg/

Comment: for some reason it highlights all the elements

Comment: I have updated the code on fiddle now you can check its working perfectly

demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/saad_jafri/nd238jfs/1/

Comment: if I clicked on "Elem 1" or "Elem 3" p tag it does not move